# Is there a formal statement of policy toward editing questions in such a way that existing answers become invalid?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I have read the [Exit strategy for chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions?s=1|5.7691) post, but I am looking for some kind of formal statement or general consensus regarding the problem of people editing their questions in such a way that existing answers become invalid.  It seems like this would be a handy resource to have, and the chameleon questions post sort of presupposes that this is a no-no, but it doesn't really say "DON'T DO THAT!".

I would especially appreciate something that is totally applicable to every SE (I'm asking because it has come up on SF&F, so SF&F should be covered by the policy), not just SO.

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that you are asking about every Stack Exchange site except the Metas - because Metas are different and allow Q&A to be used for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).  My answer below does not apply to Meta sites, only to Main sites.

I think askers should feel free to edit their questions as much as they like until the first answer has been received.

Once an answer has been received I think the asker should only make changes to their question that help clarify it further, and that do not strand the answer as being no longer applicable to the question.

I think edits to questions that strand an answer, should be rolled back.

From this point on improvement should be to the Q&A as a combined entity rather than to the question without regard to any existing answers.