# Question edited after that answer was not matched

Tags: support, reputation, answers

Suppose i answered some one's question and after some times OP was change the question body that my answer was not matched with the question. So, in future anyone else visited and found that irrelevant answer and they down-voted my answer.

This downward reputation was unwanted.

Is their any solution regarding this type of situation?

Comment: Another duplicate is https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268142/215590

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you roll-back the edit OP made. Making edits that invalidate current answers is really frowned upon. In such case OP is better off asking a new question.

I see you currently lack the required reputation to do a roll-back yourself, but if there is such an example you could always use a custom mod flag for that. Alternatively you could find a user in Chat with the required reputation to do the roll-back for you.

To rollback an answer you can click on the rollback button in the edit history, which you can access by clicking the "edited X ago" link on the bottom of a post. See attached screenshots without freehand circles.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If any edit happen without my notice how do i roll-back.For time being ,this was need to be done manually-it quite a tough task though.

Comment: In practice it depends a bit on the specific SE site. Some take answer invalidation very seriously, others tend to tolerate it.

Comment: @Md.Amirozzaman Once you have instant-edit privileges at least, there's a rollback button on every revision but the last.

Comment: @Md.Amirozzaman I added screenshots to clarify how the process can be acomplished, It is true that you do not get notified when the question is edited, but there could be someone that comments that your answer no longer works, and you could then see the question being edited.

Comment: thanks for your time-i learned a lot in last month.

Comment: @mast i have no problem with incorrect or correct,last couple of years i was learning so many things from here. when op change his question and i  get down-voted without any reason-this was unwanted.

Comment: @Md.Amirozzaman - Even if the question revision is rolled back, users can still downvote your answer, and they don't necessarily need a reason to do so.  Best to simply move forward, submit the best quality contributions, and move on to answering the next question.  The downvote your answer has earned can only be reversed by the user themselves.